# Pass over duplicate comparing for each results

Tags: php

This is a tough one. I'm completely stumped here.

Basically I have this :

```
    foreach ($getSubsSecondList as $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondList){

    $itemUse = $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondList[dir_sub_categories];

    if (!empty($itemUse)) {
    if (isset($itemUse)) {
    foreach (array_unique($getSubsSecondListAgain) as $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain){
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($itemUse);
echo "</pre><br>";
$nameStore = $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain[name]; 

    }
    }
    }
    }
```

For my `$itemUse` var_dump I have an output of

> string(16) "Health & Fitness"
>
> string(6) "Sports"
>
> string(17) "Sports - Training"
>
> string(19) "Sports & Recreation"

Exactly what I'm looking for. The problem is I have `Sports Store #1` in "Health and fitness" and in the "Sports" category. `Sports Store #1` is echoed twice. Is there a way to further break this down so that if `Sports Store #1` is found more than once it will by pass it? The actual output here is

```
Sports Store # 0
Sports Store # 1 
Sports Store # 1
```

What I'm looking for is only one instance to appear like so:

```
Sports Store # 0
Sports Store # 1
```

Comment: Use a PHP Map to ensure you only have a set of items (no duplicates). http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php

Answer (score 0):

Store what you output into an array, and if the next thing you want to output is in the array, don't print it out and move on to the next element.

```
 $outputted = array();

 foreach ($getSubsSecondList as $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondList){

    $itemUse = $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondList[dir_sub_categories];

    if (!empty($itemUse)) {
      if (isset($itemUse)) {
        foreach (array_unique($getSubsSecondListAgain) as $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain){
          if ( in_array($subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain[name], $outputted) ){
             continue;
          }
          echo "<pre>";
          var_dump($itemUse);
          echo "</pre><br>";

          echo $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain[name]; 
          $outputted[] = $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain[name];

        }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Does this change if I'm assigning a variable like this : $nameStore = $subCatDisplayExtendTwoSecondListAgain[name];   See edited OP.

Comment: You would use: `in_array($nameStore, $outputted)`

Comment: can you explain what's going on here. I'm confused and not getting the desired results. I may be able to adjust as needed, but I'm confused as to whats happening here.